# Unable to redirect after createUserWithEmailAndPassword()

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I have a form to create a firebase user using createUserWithEmailAndPassword() and a button who redirect to home page.
after I click on the button, the user account is created successfully but without redirection to another page

the button's code in **register.dart**

```
child: FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
                          email: _emailController.text,
                          password: _passwordController.text
                      ).then((signedUser){
                        UserToDatabase().addNewUser(signedUser, context);
                          Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/home');
                      }).catchError((e){
                        print(e);
                      });
                    },
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text("S'inscrire"),
                    ),
                  ),
```

**user_to_database.dart**

```
import 'package:car_app/GUI/bottomNavBar.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

class UserToDatabase{
  addNewUser(user, context){
    FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('users').push().set({
      'email' : user.email,
      'uid' : user.uid
    }).then((value){
        Navigator.push(context, new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new BottomNavBar()));
    }).catchError((e){
      print(e);
    });
  }
}
```

I want to know what should I change so I can redirect to home page.
this is what I get as error messages:

```
Performing hot reload...
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
Reloaded 3 of 474 libraries in 1 272ms.
I/BiChannelGoogleApi(17924): [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzao@711d32a
W/DynamiteModule(17924): Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
I/FirebaseAuth(17924): [FirebaseAuth:] Preparing to create service connection to gms implementation
I/art     (17924): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 20942(1058KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 31% free, 2MB/3MB, paused 29.893ms total 107.321ms
D/FirebaseAuth(17924): Notifying id token listeners about user ( YT5FSoTNCJdlUQb2msW0S01VZSf1 ).
D/FirebaseAuth(17924): Notifying auth state listeners about user ( YT5FSoTNCJdlUQb2msW0S01VZSf1 ).
I/flutter (17924): NoSuchMethodError: Class 'AuthResult' has no instance getter 'email'.
I/flutter (17924): Receiver: Instance of 'AuthResult'
I/flutter (17924): Tried calling: email
```

Comment: Have you checked your `AuthResult` for `email`?

Comment: @ConstantinBeer yes I did, but nothing changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object `user` is of type AuthResult and that class has no such getter as email.

Whenever you create a user, Firebase just let's us know if the transaction was successful or not.

You'll have to manually pass in the email as a function parameter or directly use the TextEditingController if it is accessible.

In order to know if the transaction was successful or not just use the getter user on 'user' object in the definition of the member function addnewUser of class UsertoDatabase.

```
if(user.user!=null) 
{
// pass the email ID or whatever details you need to 
// Push to next page 
}
```

Reference : https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/AuthResult-class.html

Comment: the transaction was successful. The problem is resolved after I changed the dependencies of firebase_auth by an older version. Thank you